# Highlight multiple duplicates in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a scenario with 3 columns. They hold different values in them. For example the first one is for people, the second is for some activity and the third is for a date/month. I want to know how can I highlight the entire row (or these three columns, doesn't matter) when all the values are matching. And I Don't want to highlight if I have two people with the same name or if I have one month two times. Only when the row is identical to another one.
*Keep in mind that I have other columns with diffenerent information between them (I don't want to compare the whole row with another)

For now - I have this formula  `=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$50, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN(), 4))) > 1`
Which is highlighting duplicates, but it only works for one column.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    =arrayformula(IF(IF($A1&$B1&$C1="",0,(SUMPRODUCT($A1&$B1&$C1=$A$1:$A$9&$B$1:$B$9&$C$1:$C$9))>1),1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply to A1:E9

```
      =ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A1&$B1&$C1="",0,COUNTIF($A1:$A9&$B1:$B9&$C1:$C9,$A1&$B1&$C1)>1))
```

You could change A,B,C to whatever the three columns you like: For eg. B , N &L. However, Both criteria and range  and IF must be in the same order. B1&N1&L1 must be with $B:B&$N:N&$L:L NOT $B:B&$L:L&$N:N

Comment: If this worked out for you, Mark this as the solution by clicking ✔✓✅ on the left of this post.

Comment: Thank you! But this is working partially. I need to highlight the current row in red as well. Now it's highlighting all the previous rows and all the blank ones (as they are the same too) If you can help me with this too, i'll be thankfull.

Comment: Blanks are already care of... Did you enter the IF correctly?

Comment: Oh yes, I just saw the update. But what about the current row. Can this be done?

Comment: Check my other answer.